# 'Delete' button missing when I reviewed an answer in the Low Quality Posts queue as a 20K rep user

Tags: support, bug, reputation, reviewing

I noticed that one of the [answers I recently reviewed in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/119394) didn't allow me to 'Delete', but only to 'Recommend Deletion'. [Another example here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/134069) (Normally, a user with 20K rep should be able to vote to delete answers in the Low Quality Posts queue.)

I've been reading this post in Meta SE: [Recommend deletion is treated as a delete vote for 20k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144310/162827), where it says that '*the "Delete" button changes to "Recommend deletion" when a 20k user runs out of delete votes*', however I didn't get the '*You have reached the maximum of n Deletion votes per day*' error message.

I am wondering if this is due to a recent site change or if it is a bug. I haven't noticed the 'Delete' button missing in other cases when reviewing an answer in the Low Quality Posts queue. I checked my review history and the examples I provided are the only ones I can find that are affected by this issue.

Can't seem to find anything else about this in Meta SE too. Is there a reason why the 'Delete' button was missing in my case?

Comment: Comments on MSE seem to indicate that this isn't supposed to be an intended change; maybe it was something local to Arqade itself?